# Writing Django messaging to log files as well

Tags: django, logging

This has proven difficult to find via search due to the word "message" being so ubiquitous in documentation.  I am using Django messages (`django.contrib.messages`) and would like to hook those into the logging functionality as well.  So if I have this, for example...

```
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Your account is disabled.  Please contact your administrator.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login/')
```

...I would also like the message error to get written to a specific log file via a logging handler.  Is there a way to make this happen via the call to messages (or perhaps a subclassed version of it?), or is this just going to require explicitly calling both the `messages.error()` as well as the `logger` for every message?

Comment: did you find any of the answers useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this way:

1. create a `messages`-like app in your project:

   ```
   myproject/
       messages/
           __init__.py
   ```
2. in your `__init__.py` file you can have function definitions:

   ```
   from django.contrib import messages
   import logging

   logger = logging.getLogger("messages")

   def debug(request, msg, *args, **kwargs):
       messages.debug(request, msg, *args, **kwargs)
       logger.debug(msg)

   def info(request, msg, *args, **kwargs):
       messages.info(request, msg, *args, **kwargs)
       logger.info(msg)

   def warning(request, msg, *args, **kwargs):
       messages.warning(request, msg, *args, **kwargs)
       logger.warning(msg)

   def error(request, msg, *args, **kwargs):
       messages.error(request, msg, *args, **kwargs)        
       logger.error(msg)
   ```
3. define a handler for "messages" logs in your `LOGGING` variable (in the `settings` file)
4. import your library instead of `django.contrib.messages`

It's a bit "boring" to write, but I think it's general enough to be reused in several places. Of course you can take care of redefining also other functions found in `django.contrib.messages`.

Unfortunately it does not make too much sense to talk about subclassing the django messages framework, since this is not defined as a class.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the approach I will use.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating custom `MESSAGE_STORAGE` based on existing storage to suit your needs. All you need to do is overload `add` method. For example this one based on `CookieStorage`:

```
import logging
from django.contrib.messages import constants, utils
from django.contrib.messages.storage.cookie import CookieStorage

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class CookieLoggerStorage(CookieStorage):
    def add(self, level, message, extra_tags=''):
        if message and level > constants.SUCCESS: # logs WARNING and ERROR
            logger.log(level, message)
        super(CookieLoggerStorage, self).add(level, message, extra_tags)
```

In `settings.py` add:

```
# settings.py
MESSAGE_STORAGE = "path.to.CookieLoggerStorage"
```

Just for clarity, messages.constants seems to be the same as logger level constants so you can almost feed logger with messages levels

```
django.contrib.messages.constants

DEBUG   = 10
INFO    = 20
SUCCESS = 25
WARNING = 30
ERROR   = 40

logging constants

DEBUG       10
INFO        20
WARNING     30
ERROR       40
CRITICAL    50
NOTSET      0
```